# AWS EMR Bootstrap Java Heap Size

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, emr

For AWS EMR 4.x, does anyone know how to utilize the bootstrap functionality and adjust the Java Heap size?

The current instructions I am finding on stackoverflow and the web in general are for EMR 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 4.x you will utilize a Configuration API/json as described at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html. The classic MapReduce heap sizes for map/reduce would go under the mapred-site section if that is what you are looking to adjust.